# Not able to connect to my tcp server written in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp

I have written a simple client/server app in C#.

Here is my simple server code -

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
tcpListener.Start();
TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
HandleClient(tcpClient);
```

and my client code is -

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
string serverIP = "192.168.12.101";
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), 8000);
tcpClient.Connect(endPoint);
```

When I run both apps server and client, I am able to connect to the server and able to send messages back and forth, but when I run the server on another machine I am not able to connect to the server, I have also checked that the port `8000` is not blocked on any machine.

EDIT: I checked that my server was running on `0.0.0.0:8000` because I used `IPAddress.Any` , but the ip address of the machine where server is running is `192.168.12.101` , I have no clue why am I not able to connect ?

What should I check to fix the problem or how should I fix the problem ?

Comment: how did you verify that it isn't blocked?

Comment: @DanielA.White  I actually created a new inbound rule for unblocking port 8000 in windows firewall.

Comment: Can you `ping` or `telnet` from your client machine to `192.168.12.101`?

Comment: could your network be restricting it too?

Comment: @npinti When I try to ping the ip address I get request timed out. Why do I get request timed out ?

Comment: Are you trying to access the server through a web browser? If that is the case, browsers attempt to connect to port 80 of the provided IP provided that you did not provide one yourself. This will fail if there is nothing listening on port 80. Using `ping` or `telnet` command you send a packet of data directly to the machine. `telnet` is actually better because you can specify the port.

Comment: @npinti I used telnet to open the host with port but it also fails saying Connect failed, what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: @npinti When I used command netstat -an to find the port, I see my server is running on 0.0.0.0:9090

Comment: @Newto.Net: It would seem that the server is running on a different port. I think that you now know why your application isn't connecting to your server application.

Comment: @npinti I am sorry that was writing mistake the port is actually, 8000, that means i am still not able to connect to my server.

Comment: @Newto.Net: This could mean either firewall rules, blocked ports, different networks etc. I'd recommend you ask a new question, maybe to some other stack exchange site which handles networking issues specifically and provide the information you've found.